# JS referenceError: change is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, function, onkeyup, referenceerror

I have 4 input boxes that call a function when the key is lifted using the `onkeyup` event. For some reason, I am getting an error saying that "change" (the function's name) is not defined. I am definitely defining the function correctly, so I have no idea what's causing this.

The demo will explain much better than me:
[image]
<sub>(source: [snag.gy](http://i.snag.gy/AieOg.jpg))</sub>

OK, got it. I was getting that error, but the cause what not what I had suspected. http://jsfiddle.net/qWcZ6/2/

Comment: I don't get that error ... what do you do to get it?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: @KevinBoucher All the code is in the Fiddle

Comment: There is a syntax error because `variable` is a DOM element not a string

Comment: @ExplosionPills The error is caused by changing either `m`, `x`, `y`, or `b` in the top equation in the demo.

Comment: The 'change' function is being called as expected for me in your JSFiddle demo.

Comment: The expected behavior is that, for example, if you change `m`, all of the other `m`s will change also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but the following works ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWcZ6/1/)):

```
function change(variable) {
    var value = $(variable).val();
    alert(value);
    $(variable).html(value);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself very well. What I want is to change all of the variables in the demo. EX: when I change `m`, it changes all of the `m`s

Comment: Or maybe not ;), at least I thought it did what he wants plus it works.

Comment: Oh, I see-I didn't put the variable passed to the function in quotes, so it's not a strong like I expected, it's a variable

Comment: It probably doesn't. I half read the question and then went to the fiddle and made it do what I thought you wanted it to do. I think I might have deserved that downvote.

Comment: I'm going to mark it as the answer anyway, because it did move me toward fixing it: http://jsfiddle.net/qWcZ6/2/

Comment: Exactly. You're passing an HTML element to your function not a string. To turn it into a jQuery object you just need to pass it to the jquery function as is. I'll read the question properly and have a look at your fiddle and see if I can figure out what you need to do.

Comment: I fixed it now; it just required sending the element as well as a string

Comment: That's great, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better pattern.

```
<mtext><input id="y" value="y" class="vars"></input></mtext>
<mo>=</mo>
<mtext><input id="m" value="m" class="vars"></input></mtext>
<mo>&#x00D7;</mo>
<mtext><input id="x" value="x" class="vars"></input></mtext>
<mo>+</mo>
<mtext><input id="b" value="b" class="vars"></input></mtext>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        function change() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            //alert(value);
            if (console && typeof console.log !== 'undefined') {
                console.log("value",value);
            }
        }
        $('.vars').on('keyup',change);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BELIKEMIKE/WAcLW/2/